# Custom interrupt to run a function

Tags: python

I have a distance sensor and a motor connected to RPi.
I am using sensor values to decide which direction the motor rotates.
Script runs and motor gets its direction.

Now I would like to press a button on the keyboard and want the script to break the running loop and execute a function "goHome()" but that doesn't seem work.
I will appreciate your help.

Thanks

```
def runcntrl():
    global mode

    while True:
        logic()
       
        
        time.sleep(0.05)

def logic():
  print(dist)
  
               
        
  if dist > target+tol:
    motorforward()
  elif dist>=target and dist<=target+tol:
    motorturnoff()
  else:
    motorreverse()
    
  while True:  
      try:
          if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
              print('Go Home!')
              goHome()
      except:
          break
```

Comment: Does it print `Go Home!`?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov no, just h and sensor output continues

Comment: It's not clear what is the `keyboard` module you use. Maybe it doesn't catch events from your particular keyboard. Or maybe it throws an exception and you just `break` (try to print the exception insteadin the `except` block)

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I am using this module from pip install keyboard I tried to print "Nothing" instead of break and I now only get Nothing printed. No sensor values.

Comment: So something fails, try `except Exception as e: print(e)`. Or just remove the try-except to see the message

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I tried if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
    print('Go Home!')  # same issue. just see h and sensor values keep scrolling

Comment: Do you wrap the `logic` function in some other try-except block somewhere else? Try to do another suggestion I gave: `except Exception as e: print(e)`. It should output the error message

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov yes you are correct. I do have a different block where logic() is executed. except Exception as e: print(e) shows just one sensor value and then no output on the terminal



def runcntrl():
    global mode

    while True:
        logic()
       
        
        time.sleep(0.05)

Comment: I updated the original code in the post.

Comment: I would be thankful if someone could suggest a solution.